# iptables SSH connection logging

Tags: ssh, iptables, logging, configuration, sles

Is it possible to only write a log-entry when a connection is established ?
I have tried:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-level notice --log-prefix "outgoing ssh connection"
```

to log outgoing SSH connections but this logs every single packet and this is as you can imagine a bit overwhelming for monitoring purposes.
I am running SLES 11 SP3.
So I would be grateful if anyone could point out a way to only write a log-entry when the conenction is established.

Comment: Did you try adding the `--state NEW` flag?

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i was looking for :) must have overlooked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Line you would need to log the traffic, might look possible as:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-prefix "Outgoing SSH connection"
```

On another terminal view the logs

`while :; do iptables -L OUTPUT -v -n --line-n; sleep 2; done`

I am using -m state --state. However I would recommand to use  `--ctstate`

`man iptables` for more.

If you feel that you are being overwhelmed by the logs, you might consider changing the `--log-level`.  http://www.netfilter.org/ can tell you more.

Comment: This worked wonders for me to track down a compromised server, but I used tail -F /var/log/syslog | grep "Outgoing SSH connection" because it only output information when a connection was attempted vs constant output.

Answer (score 3):

[val0x00ff's suggestion of using `--state`](https://serverfault.com/a/532849/58408), also by [Petter H in a comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/532848/iptables-ssh-connection-logging#comment610317_532848), should work well.

However, you don't need to introduce session state tracking just for that. You can add the `--syn` flag to make the rule match only packets with the SYN flag set, which is set only on new connection attempts.